# Is "development downtown" correct in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

I this NYtimes Headline:

"Local leaders hope that a new streetcar system would jump-start development downtown."

is: "development downtown" correct?

had I been wrtiten this, I would have thought of:

1 - jump-start development of downtown

or

2 - jump-start the downtown development

Comment: ***downtown*** in the cited example *adverbially* modifies tthe "head" noun ***development***, as per your "rephrasing" #2 (which simply adds the entirely optional / contextually meaningless definite article ***the*** as a stylistic choice). Your *first* rephrasing is syntactically valid, but probably less likely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't understand how "downtown" adverbially modifies the noun "development" being downtown a noun as well? other point, what if a remove the definite article from rephrasing #2 would that make it correct?

Comment: As I said, the definite article is irrelevant here, both syntactically and semantically. Note that ***downtown*** isn't something that can be "jump-started" - only ***development*** can fit that role. I don't think it's meaningful to ask whether ***downtown*** is an "adverb" or a "noun" - it's being ***used*** adverbially, even if we categorize it as a ***noun adjunct** used adverbially*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't know I could use a noun  adverbially, only to my will. I mean not abiding to any grammatical rule

Comment: Have a look at some questions returned by [searching for "noun adjunct"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22noun+adjunct%22) on this site. But do ***not*** waste your time trying to decide whether to call the usage a "noun", "adjective", or "adverb". That's not a useful categorisation in this context.

Comment: https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/downtown categorizes this use as a preposition (forming a one-word prepositional phrase). It could be substituted with the prepositional phrase "in the city center".

Comment: @nschneid: I leave it to others to decide on terminology here. So far as I'm concerned, all such labels are probably not worth bothering with in contexts where different people assign *different* labels. The categories themselves aren't "real" - they're just conventional descriptions that *might* help people understand things. But they probably won't help anyone if all we're doing is discussing which label to use in some specific context.

Comment: Berinja tela - See [What Is an Adverbial Noun?](https://www.languagehumanities.org/what-is-an-adverbial-noun.htm). Hopefully when you've finished, you'll agree that *I drove **for an hour*** and *I drove **north*** are "adverbial" usages (even though ***north*** and ***an hour*** are essentially "nouns"), but *I drove **my car*** isn't "adverbial" - ***my car*** is just a noun serving as the ***object*** of the verb.

Comment: @all, what is intriguing me in this question is somehow I belive it should be: "downtown development" for the fact in my head ake more sense that donwtown modifies development get it? I mean the text is  talking about a development in general, what kind of development? a downtown kind

Answer (score 1):

"Downtown" is an adverb here, meaning "in the downtown area."