# should words be flip around for correct understanding?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

In this Headline:

"Local leaders hope that a new streetcar system would jump-start development downtown."

the way I see it: "development downtown" should be inverted to "downtown development"

makes more sense to me thta the text is talking about the development of a downtown, so I think in my lack of English writing experience that it is clearer to use dvelopment as head noun and downtown as a noun adjective modifying development, is that correct?

Comment: You already asked this yesterday. Please don't repost. Does this answer your question? [Is "development downtown" correct in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331603/is-development-downtown-correct-in-this-context)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, sorry for responding. I believe this is a "spin off" question that was generated by comments you've provided in the other post

Comment: @FumbleFingers, this question has a different point of view from the question asked in the other post

Comment: Ask for clarification there. Don't start a new post about what's basically the same thing.

Comment: _Downtown_ is an American term for '_in or to_ the central part of a city'. I don't think they say 'a downtown'.

Comment: I do not think the **answer** to the referenced post is helpful. Saying that post-positioning “development” makes it an adverb may be technically correct, but does not address the question of whether one placement is more idiomatic or whether different placements significantly affect meaning.

Comment: I should add that this question is better posed than the question in the referenced post and that I found the comments (rather than the actual answer) to the question in the referenced post helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Headlines are not the best way to analyze English grammar because they are highly constrained in length. Furthermore, “downtown” is a compound noun consisting of a preposition plus a noun: its roots in a prepositional phrase are obvious.

This headline is not talking about the development of a “downtown” in the sense of creating an area of a city or town that is called that by local inhabitants. Your use of the indefinite article in “a downtown” implies that you may be thinking in that sense.

It is talking about the expansion or renovation of an area or part of an area already called “downtown.” The sense is redevelopment within an already developed and designated area.

Syntactically, placing “downtown” before “development” makes “downtown” look like an adjective (adjectives normally precede the noun being modified) whereas placing “downtown” after “development” makes “downtown” look like a prepositional phrase of place (which usually follow the noun being modified).

We could argue all day and to little purpose about what is the most useful way to categorize the **syntactical** difference (if any) between the different placements of “downtown,” but both placements are idiomatic ways to express the same thought, namely to specify the development in question by its physical location. The word “downtown” is being used as a modifier of “development,” and as such either placement can be idiomatic.

Comment: you mean "downtown development" and "development downtown" in this context are the same?

Comment: There may be some slight nuance intended. Headlines are not noted for effectively conveying nuance. But, as a native, educated  speaker of American English I do not see any difference in meaning conveyed by the different placements of “downtown.” As FF commented in the other post, the post-positioning **usually** seems more euphonious to me because “downtown” sounds so much like a prepositional phrase, but I have certainly seen usages where pre-positioning is more natural, *e.g.*, “Downtown Merchants’ Association.”